# Filtering file 2 based on file 1 ($1 and $2)

Tags: arrays, awk, multiple-columns

I am attempting to filter my secondary file based on my first file. I need them to be the same amount of rows so I thought to store each of my two first columns (since they are the ones that would have unique ids) in an array and cross check it with the second file. Below is my one liner. I have filtered with my first array successfully but implementing the second one is causing me issues. Below is my sample data, they are all tab delimited.

**Code**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{position[$2]++;next}$2 in position' && 'NR==FNR{chrm[$1]++next}$1 in chrm' file1 file2
```

**Sample Data**

**File 1**

```
ID        Pos     E       N
unique1   15       0.01   0.02
unique1   18       0.01   0.02  
unique1   12       0.01   0.02  
unique2   20       0.01   0.02  
unique2   23       0.01   0.02  
unique2   27       0.01   0.02  
unique2   20       0.01   0.02  
unique3   25       0.01   0.02  
unique3   35       0.01   0.02  
unique3   42       0.01   0.02
```

**File 2**

```
ID        Pos     E       N
unique1   15       0.01   0.02
unique2   27       0.01   0.02  
unique2   20       0.01   0.02  
unique3   24       0.01   0.02  
unique3   150      0.01   0.02  
unique3   227      0.01   0.02
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
ID        Pos     E       N
unique1   15       0.01   0.02
unique2   27       0.01   0.02  
unique2   20       0.01   0.02
```

I don't understand why && is not treating my second array as a set of parameters to create my output. It is giving me a blank file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]; next} ($1,$2) in a' file1 file2

ID        Pos     E       N
unique1   15       0.01   0.02
unique2   27       0.01   0.02  
unique2   20       0.01   0.02
```

your `&&` is outside of the `awk` script, which you don't need anyway...

Comment: Oh would it have been okay if it was kept inside the ' '?

Comment: No, not in this way.  The logical or should be in between conditions, not statements (i.e. `NR==FNR && NR>1`)

Comment: Ah, I see. I have tested it and it works! thanks! I will accept the answer once it allows me to.